# Celery error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'task'

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I am going through [First steps with celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) and trying to create a task as shown in the example:

```
from celery import Celery;

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost'),
    
@app.task
def add(x,y):
    return x + y
```

When I try to run the worker using:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

It says:

```
Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
Unable to load celery application.
'tuple' object has no attribute 'task'
```

But I am able to start my worker through command line using:

```
celery -b 'redis://localhost' worker
```

What am I doing wrong?

Meta:

- File name:  tasks.py
- Python version: 3.9.0
- Celery version: 5.0.5
- I have created a fresh virtual environment using venv
- I am trying to start the worker from the same directory where my tasks.py file exists

Comment: There's a comma at the end of `app = Celery(...` line. That's the tuple the error message is about. Remove it and it should be fine.